# Abstract class: Which exception should I throw when child classes aren't implemented correctly?

Tags: .net, exception, inheritance, abstract-class

Lets say I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class MyAbstract
{
    protected abstract object ImplementMePlz();

    public object DoSomething()
    {
        // Some logic here

        var result = ImplementMePlz();
        if (result == null)
            throw new YourChildClassIsStupidException("ImplementMePlz() should never return null.");

        return result;
    }
}
```

What kind of exception should I throw in this scenario? Is there a designated exception in the .NET framework, or should I create my own custom exception?

Comment: I would throw `ArgumentNullException` but I'm not sure if that totally fits.

Comment: What's wrong with the `YourChildClassIsStupidException` exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question "Is there a designated exception in the .NET framework?" is "no" - there is no such exception.

If I were you, I would create a custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own exception class. The framework has no exception that I know of to handle this situation. Why? I don't think the framework has a need for this exception.

Also, I'd suggest using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to prevent the exception in the first place.

Comment: True, but you do have to worry about the stuff in the derived class not being implemented *correctly*.

Comment: Ah, updating answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

This depends on why your child class has returned null. It may make more sense to throw the exception in the child class as it will have a better idea why it's returning null and can produce a more informative exception.

If you have no control over the child class then you should do one of two things.

1. You can infer some information from the null return. You should create an exception that passes on that knowledge e.g. The API states that you should return null if one of you inputs is invalid, throw an InvalidArgumentExpection.
2. You just know that it shouldn't be null, if which case, throw ArgumentNull exception or something similar

Comment: The problem is I'm not necessarily going to be the one who writes the child class. If I'm writing an API, anyone can write the child class, and they need to know that returning null simply will not work. Basically, the exception is for the developer's benefit, not the user's.